# C# RegExp for search inner pattern

Tags: c#, regex, text

I have a string like this:

```
[[[a]]][[[b]]][[[c]]]
```

I want to extract these:

```
a
b
c
```

So I wrote the following pattern:

```
@"\[\[\[(.+?)\]\]\]"
```

using the following code

```
string input = "[[[a]]][[[b]]][[[c]]]";
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\[\[\[(.+?)\]\]\]");
foreach (Match er in regexObj.Matches(input)) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(er.Value); 
}
```

the result is:

```
[[[a]]]
[[[b]]]
[[[c]]]
```

What is the matter? Could you help me?

Comment: string input = "[[[a]]][[[b]]][[[c]]]";
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\[\[\[(.+?)\]\]\]");
            foreach (Match er in regexObj.Matches(input))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(er.Value);
            }

Comment: You are getting the matches but you aren't looking for the groups' captures: er.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value.

Comment: @Boggin `Groups[0]` is the whole match.

Comment: Such an easy question while I was having breakfast? Unfair. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `er.Value` you need to use `er.Groups[1].Value`.

`er.Value` is the same as `er.Groups[0].Value`, and it contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern.  Each subsequent element, from index one upward, represents a captured group.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[^\p{Ps}\p{Pe}]
```

This uses the unicode opening and closing brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Why not this pattern (it gives the correct output for your example)?

```
[a-z]
```

Comment: What if real strings (not simplified for the question) contains not only a-z, and OP needs exactly extract values inside square brackets?